# Expand date ranges for aggregations on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have create a dimension with a series of values and From/To fields and stored it all on elasticsearch.

I now need to create aggregations on some attributes but expanded by day on the range of dates given. For instance, I have the following:

```
Location       Sales Region  From        To

San Francisco  West          1/1/2013    12/01/2013
Oakland        West          12/02/2013  04/05/2014
```

But now, I need an aggregate to return

```
Date, Location, Count(*)

1/1/2013, San Francisco, 1

1/2/2013, San Francisco, 2

...

12/02/2013 Oakland 1

...

04/05/2014 Oakland 1
```

Can you give me a tip how to blow up my range so this can happen or if elastic search already offers something similar?

Comment: Are you using just elasticsearch, or is the goal to ultimately present a histogram in Kibana?

Comment: I am using elastic search. I am planning to create analytics using d3. I could put the 13M+ records that my dataset is composed of but this dataset with from - to is only 450K records. If I could do the aggregations on elastic search would be great. 

If not possible, then I can retrieve the records and then do the expansion of dates once the records are retrieved, but that would add time and not sure how fast will this be. Any idea?